# Is it possible to get data from the 2nd table using column in 1st table using PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Well, I have a situation that I need to `SELECT` data from two tables at once. But my main problem is how can I `SELECT .. WHERE` in my table2 when the value that I needed in `WHERE clause` is in the return value of `SELECT` statement in table1.

**test.php**

```
<?php 
   include("../../connection.php");
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $id= $data->id;

    try{
      $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");  
      $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM tblstudents WHERE studID=':id';
        SELECT * FROM tblparents WHERE studNumber=':studNumber';
      ";

      $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
      $statement->bindValue(":id", $id);
      $statement->bindValue(":studNumber", $studNumber);

      $result = $statement->execute();

      echo json_encode($result);

    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

The `studNumber` value is in the `tblstudents` which will have a return value from `SELECT` statement.

Is it possible that I can get the `studNumber` value in the return value of `SELECT` statement when the `SELECT` statement of the `tblparents` is in the same `sql query`? Or is there another way around?

Hope I clearly explained my situation.

Comment: I think you need `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @JYoThI, Okay thanks I will try that.

Comment: Read about joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN` for get data from multiple tables. Try this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblstudents JOIN tblparents on
 tblstudents.studNumber  = tblparents.studNumber  WHERE tblstudents.studID=:id;"

  $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
  $statement->bindValue(":id", $id);
  $result = $statement->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for your provided answer. Sorry for late accept of the answer.